# Does the reliability of polynomial hashing depend on whether the modulus is prime, for coprime base and modulus?

Tags: probabilistic-algorithms, hashing, polynomials, modular-arithmetic

A polynomial hash of a string $s$ with base $b$ and modulus $M$ is defined as

$$
H(s) = (s_0 + s_1 b + s_2 b^2 + \dots + s_{n-1} b^{n-1}) \mod M.
$$

I have proven (and this is quite obvious) that collisions are more likely if $b$ and $M$ have common factors.

I have also proven that if $b \perp M$ and $s_i$ are random numbers in range $\left[0; M\right)$, the probability that a hash is zero (and, therefore, the approximate probability of collision) is $\frac{1}{M}$. This seems to imply that, as long as $b \perp M$, it does not matter whether $M$ is prime or not.

However, for all practical purposes, including when implementing polynomial hashing manually, prime $M$ is considered more reliable than a similar (and possibly twofold larger) power of two. Why is that so? Does the answer depend on the magnitude of $b$ and whether $s_i$ are arbitrary numbers from $\mathbb{Z}/M\mathbb{Z}$ or are from a lesser subset of the ring, e.g. alphabetic characters?

P.S. I am aware of the well-known and easily constructible anti-hash tests for powers of two. The question is about more "random" input, I am asking about the probability of two uniformly random strings colliding, or the probability of two "similar" strings colliding.

Answer (score 1):

It does matter.  Primes are better, at least in some sense.  If we choose $b$ randomly, then the probability of a collision between two different strings is at most $n/M$ when $M$ is prime, but can be much higher when $M$ is not prime.  In particular, when $M$ is prime and $b$ is random, this hash function is [2-universal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_hashing), and is known as [the multiplicative hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_hashing#Hashing_strings).  If $b$ is not random but is a fixed value, then the situation is less clear -- it is harder to formulate a precise definition of what counts as "good" -- but the above provides some evidence why primes are better.

It seems you are evaluating the probability of a collision if you hash two strings that are each chosen uniformly and independently at random.  That is relatively easy to achieve.  What is more challenging to achieve is to ensure that, for every pair of different strings, the probability of collision is low (e.g., the probability of collision is low even if the two strings are similar or related).  The latter is achieved by 2-universal hash functions.

So, one intuitive way to explain why it might be better to choose $M$ as a prime is that we expect it may be better in situations where you hash two related strings.  I think those kinds of situations arise frequently in practice.  That said, as a heuristic, you can always use a non-prime value of $M$.  If it is good enough in your application, then all's well.  In practice the worst case situations often don't arise, and even imperfect hash functions can often do well.